# PostgreSQL - How to display a corresponding string on every entry in string_agg()?

Tags: postgresql, select, string-aggregation

I have 2 tables:

```
Employee
ID   Name
1    John
2    Ben
3    Adam

Employer
ID   Name
1    James
2    Rob
3    Paul
```

I want to string_agg() and concatenate the two tables in one record as a single column. Now I wanted another column than will determine that if that string is from "Employee" table, it will display "Employee" and "Employer" if the data comes from the "Employer" table.

Here's my code for displaying the table:

```
SELECT string_agg(e.Name, CHR(10)) || CHR(10) || string_agg(er.Name, CHR(10)), PERSON_STATUS
FROM Employee e, Employer er
```

Here's my expected output:

```
ID    Name    PERSON_STATUS
1     John    Employee
      Ben     Employee
      Adam    Employee
      James   Employer
      Rob     Employer
      Paul    Employer
```

NOTE: I know this can be done by adding another column in the table but that's not the case of this scenario. This is just an example to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Is your expected output a single string, or a result set showing 3 columns?

Comment: @Scoots the "Name" column and the "PERSON_STATUS" column are strings. "Name" column comes from the 2 tables.

Comment: And you want all those names/statuses to be a single row, right?

Comment: @eurotrash Exactly sir!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, I'd say that you need `UNION ALL` rather than an aggregate:

```
SELECT id, name, 'Employee'::text AS person_status
FROM employee
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, 'Employer'::text
from employer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first we merge our 2 tables into 3 columns. We can select arbitrary values this way.

```
select
    "ID", -- Double quotes are necesary for capitalised aliases
    "Name",
    'Employee' as "PERSON_STATUS"
from
    employee
union
select
    "ID",
    "Name",
    'Employer'
from
    employer
```

We then subquery this and perform our string operations as required.

```
select
    string_agg(concat(people."Name", '    ', people."PERSON_STATUS"), chr(10))
from
    (
        select
            "ID",
            "Name",
            'Employee' as "PERSON_STATUS"
        from
            employee
        union
        select
            "ID",
            "Name",
            'Employer'
        from
            employer
    ) as people
```

Comment: I prefer to use the subquery because I have multiple select here also from other table. Does sub-query affect the overall performance of my stored procedure?

Comment: Postgres is pretty good at optimising subqueries - to see the full effect you'd need to compare your existing process and my suggestion by using `explain analyze`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will try this later. Will indicate your answer accepted if it's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 AS id, STRING_AGG(name, E'\r\n') AS name, STRING_AGG(person_status, E'\r\n') AS person_status
FROM (
        SELECT name, 'Employee' AS person_status
        FROM employee
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name, 'Employer'
        FROM employer
) data
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will try this later. Will indicate your answer accepted if it's the best answer.

Comment: "Thank you for your answer! Will try this later. Will indicate your answer accepted if it's the best answer." @JPDolocanog without `ORDER BY` clause(s) you **can't** trust anny DBMS to always give that same order..